# I do not want scrolling to be possible when the cart overlay is opened

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

When the user opens the cart overlay, scrolling of the background shouldn't be possible. I have searched and i can't seem to find a workable way around it.
Here's the code.

```
class CartMenu extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false,
    };
    this.dropdownRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.setCartCloseFunc(this.closeMenu);
  }

  setOpenOrClosed() {
    this.setState(
      (prevState) => ({ open: !prevState.open }),
      () => {
        this.props.onCartButtonClicked(this.state.open);
      }
    );
  }
```

This is a snippet of the code. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the root html element of your app (usually with id="root")
2. Then when your cart is open, set the root element a `overflow: hidden` css
3. And when it's false, set it back to `unset`

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you problem, you are in a React environment.
What you need here is to make the body not scrollable anymore. Fortunately for you, body isn't in the scope of React, only what's in div#app is (if I remember the basics of React).

You basically need to toggle the `overflow: hidden` state of the body element, by using JS, or CSS and JS.

### Only JS

Using only JS, you need to use this:

```js
// to block the scroll
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";

// to make it scrollable again
document.body.style.overflow = "unset";
```

### JS and CSS combined

If you prefer using a class toggle and CSS, you can use the classList API.

```js
// to block the scroll
document.body.classList.add('no-scroll');

// to make it scrollable again
document.body.classList.remove('no-scroll');
```

with this CSS

```
body.no-scroll {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

### Good to know

I know some version of mobile OS doesn't like this way.
If you want, you can do the same with this small library: [body-scroll-lock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-scroll-lock)

I hope I could help

Comment: It does not work on woodmart theme when mini cart is being opened.